# Making images slide and resize as the video plays with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, image-scaling

I want to create a video where I have multiple images on screen at once which are moving around or resizing as the video plays.

A vastly more advanced version would be like Facebooks https://www.facebook.com/lookback/

All I need, is to move a few images and change their scale, with set start and end times within the video.

I could obviously do this with a video editor but I'd like to just drop some images in a directory and then have a preset script which will then create the video for me.

I've a few months experience with FFMPEG so the directory part is easy, but I'm baffled on the moving bits.

Any suggestions? Many thanks.

Comment: possibly ask on the ffmpeg-user mailing list...

Comment: You may be able to do something with [FFmpeg Expression Evaluation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) and the [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) and [`scale`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) video filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you might consider the [MLT framework](http://www.mltframework.org/) which is essentially the open-source video editor which supports scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Considering use swfcombine with pyvnc2swf and ffmpeg.

With SWF you can replace objects into a exist swf file link image or texts.
http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/swftools-common/2005-02/msg00116.html

Aftes editing your swf you can render a mp4 file using pyvnc2swf and ffmpeg:
http://imnartist.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/pyvnc2swf-and-ffmpeg-tutorial-convert.html

Unfortunatly ffmpeg don't convert swf yet.

With those tools you can recreate the Facebook Look Back web app for your porpuse using command line and you favorite programming language.

Answer (score 0):

There's an API to do so too :you can use the Stupeflix API to do server side video renderings, using After Effects templates or built-in effects. Find it at http://developer.stupeflix.com/documentation, with a lot of other tools to do image / video processing.